# Display dataframe as an HTML table with conditional colouring based on another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (mtcars). It has columns with names: mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs
I want to compare each column with vs ( column 1 vs column 8, column 2 vs column 8 and etc) and colour each column from 1: 7 as red (if the element is less than that of one in column8), yellow (if equal) or green (if greater).

I have used KableExtra package and used the below code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
mtcars %>%
 mutate(
   car = row.names(.),
   mpg = cell_spec(mpg, "html", background = ifelse(mpg > vs, "green", "red")),
   cyl = cell_spec(cyl, "html", background = ifelse(cyl > vs,"green", "red" )),
 ) %>%
 kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
 kable_styling("striped", full_width = F)
```

I could achieve somehow but have two major issues:

1. KableExtra does not produce cell background as a tile/fill in Html it just highlights text in cell. I see latex can produce cell background but I can not use latex need only html solution.
2. In my actual data frame there are 70 dynamic columns and therefore need to access columns without names.

Tried with condformat and tableHTML too...but could not achieve comparing columns dynamically.

Comment: Perhaps check out the DT package: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/. See this link for (conditional) row and column styling: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

Comment: Unfortunately DT doesn't seem to have function to compare between columns but to with a constant number...

Comment: @doctshinds: a workaround is to add a set of (hidden) columns to the data used for formatting, see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to use column styling with the DT package is by adding a set of dummy columns used to set the background colors in `formatStyle`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

## add dummy columns for formatting
mtcarsColor <- mutate_all(mtcars, list(color = ~case_when(
            . < mtcars$vs ~ -1,
            . > mtcars$vs ~  1,
            TRUE ~ 0
        )
    )
)

## relevant column indices
dataCols <- grep("color", names(mtcarsColor), invert = TRUE) 
colorCols <- grep("color", names(mtcarsColor))

## datatable formatted by (hidden) dummy columns
datatable(mtcarsColor,
        rownames = FALSE,
        options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = colorCols - 1)))    
    ) %>%
    formatStyle(columns = dataCols,
        valueColumns = colorCols,
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("-1", "0", "1"), c("#FF000080", "#FFFF0080", "#00FF0080"))
    )
```

[image: DT with background colors]

Comment: What a brilliant idea...I have been struggling for days! Thank you so much. Just to learn, how would i use the above methodology in htmlTable? I tried using: `x <- head(cars)
where <- rbind(c(2,2), c(2,1), c(5,2))
style <- c('background-color: red; color: white;',
           'border: solid 1px;',
           'font-weight: 900; color: blue;')
css.cell <- matrix('', nrow(x), ncol(x))
css.cell[where] <- style

htmlTable(head(cars), css.cell = css.cell)` emailing html table,from DT seems very big therefore tried to replicate using htmlTable...could you have a look at pls?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by 'emailing html table,from DT seems very big'? Do you mean you are emailing the raw html generated by `DT::datatable`?

Comment: I would like to insert the html table generated by DT in the body of email using mailR package, I think since DT table html codes are with search and other settings, it's not displayed in receivers email body. But when I attach its visible. If I insert table made by htmlTable this does not happen. Here color is changed by simple css and html code is very light  therefore to enable mailing I should produce light weight html table.